# How to add OUTLINE on input tags?

Tags: html, css

In google chrome, when an input tag is selected then appear a yellow outline around it.

In other browser ( firefox, explorer, ecc ) not !!

How can I add outlines on input tags in other browser ( firefox, explorer ) like chrome ??

Answer (score 2):

You could use `outline` with the limitation that it doesn't work in IE6/7:

```
outline: 3px orange solid;
```

the only alternative that works across all browsers is `border` but that will take away the element's native border, something you may not want.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqrmE/)

Comment: How can I add this outline only when the input tag is selected :) ?

Comment: What @ClarkeyBoy says. `input:focus { ... } `

Comment: If you dont mind using CSS3, despite its poor support in earlier browsers, you can always use `input[type=text]:focus` to specify just textboxes, or you can apply this to other specific elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have some options to try.

outline, border, and pseudo-element :focus.